# As I have updated the ngx-store version in my package.json. Error occurs:

Tags: angular

As I have updated my Angular Compiler version to 7.1.4 and typescript version to 3.1.1. Here comes the problem. 
 -> error TS2420: Class 'NgxStorageEvent' incorrectly implements interface 'StorageEvent'.
Property 'composedPath' is missing in type 'NgxStorageEvent'.
 -> error TS2420: Class 'Debugger' incorrectly implements interface 'Console'.
Property 'memory' is missing in type 'Debugger'.

Comment: downgraded ngx-store version to 1.4.1. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

"typescript": "~3.1.1" which can be found in root package.json. See what your typescript version for application using by running `npm list typescript` inside your application root directory.